# how to handle mouse events of parent window in wxwidgets

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wxwidgets

I having a parent window on top of that there is a child window , how handle mouse events from child window to parent window.

here is my code:

```
   //parent class
   IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC_CLASS(MWParent, wxPanel)
    BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MWParent, wxPanel) 
    EVT_LEFT_DCLICK(MWParent::OnMouseLeftDClick)
    EVT_RIGHT_DOWN(MWParent::OnMouseRightclick)
    END_EVENT_TABLE()

    MWParent::MWParent()
    {
    }
    MWParent::~MWParent()
    {

    }
    MWParent::MWParent( wxWindow *win , long id ):wxPanel( win , id ){
            MWChild *obj = new MWChild(this);
    }

   //child class

    IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC_CLASS(MWChild, wxPanel)
    BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MWChild, wxPanel) 
    END_EVENT_TABLE()

    MWChild::MWChild()
    {
    }
    MWChild::~MWChild()
    {

    }
    MWChild::MWChild( wxWindow *win , long id ):wxPanel( win , id ){


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Bind()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_evt_handler.html#a0f30c8fa5583b4a5f661897d63de3b62) to connect the child event to a handler in any other window, possibly the parent one.

See [the event handling overview](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_events.html) for more information.